# Matrix to String, new lines for rows matlab

Tags: string, matlab, string-concatenation

Title basically says it all.
Here is my current code, but it's not quite correct. It puts \n rather than a new line.

I would like to go through a row of a matrix, put a space between each element in the row and then add a new line for the next row.

```
mat = [1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8]; %must work for arbitrary size matrix.. just an example
s = '';
for i = 1:size(mat,1)
  s = strcat(s,sprintf('%d ',mat(i,:)));
  s = [s,'\n']; %and many variations of trying to add this 
end
```

This currently yields:
`1 2 3 4\n5 6 7 8\n`

What I would like is (as a string):

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

I don't know how I haven't found someone asking this specific question before, but I have searched to no avail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A newline is character code 10 (`char(10)`). So, you can keep your current `sprintf` and use `char(10)`:

```
s = [s,char(10)];
```

Here is what happens with a simple example:

```
>> ['one' char(10) 'two']
ans =
one
two
```

It turned out that `strcat` strips the newline, so replace the content of the loop with:

```
s = [s sprintf('%d ',mat(i,:)) char(10)];
```

From the [`strcat` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html):

> For character array inputs, strcat removes trailing ASCII white-space
>       characters: space, tab, vertical tab, newline, carriage return, and
>       form-feed. To preserve trailing spaces when concatenating character
>       arrays, use horizontal array concatenation, `[s1, s2, ..., sN]`.

Also, `num2str` *might* also do what you want, but if you have more than 1 digit in each number than your output would be a little different:

```
>> num2str(mat)
ans =
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9  10  11  12
```

Another funky solution with no loop:

```
>> s = sprintf([repmat('%d ',1,size(mat,2)) '\n'],mat')
s =
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not quite my question. The problem is adding a new line AFTER the last column. This will add a new line after each column.

Comment: @user2243357: I just updated the answer. The bit `s = [s,char(10)];` is probably what you need.

Comment: I actually need it to work for an arbitrary size matrix. Also, s = [s,char(10)] doesn't work. It yields a new line only after the last row for some reason.. And gives '1 2 3 45 6 7 8'

Comment: It will give a new line, but then when it reloops strcat seems to ignore it the next iteration (and thus the numbers are crunched together ie: 45)

Comment: I am on windows 7. It does give a new line for me too, but only after the very last row (when the loop is in its terminating iteration). Debug testing, it yields a new line at first, but when it goes back through the loop the new line disappears (my guess is strcat is ignoring it).

Comment: @user2243357 Yes, that is it.  `strcat` is stripping the newline.  If you replace the `strcat` line with `s = [s sprintf(..) char(10)];`, it works.

Comment: Thanks! I should have tried num2str first..  I used a similar built in method and it didn't work so I assumed num2str wouldn't work either. Now it looks like a stupid question >.< !

Comment: @user2243357 No, not at all.  It adds extra spaces, so I can see how you might not want that.